# Label button needs double click to show menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following problem: When I click on the label-"button" (hamburger menu) I have to double to click to show the menu the second time around.

I think is a conflict beween CSS and jQuery.

The intended code behavior is the following: When you click #NavDark I want to hide .MainMenu and #NavDark itself, when you click the label I want to show them both.

```js
$("#NavDark").click(function() {
  $(".MainMenu").hide();
  $("#NavDark").hide();

});


$("#toggle").click(function() {
  $(".MainMenu,#NavDark").show();

});
```

```css
.ButtonMenu label:checked~.MainMenu {
  display: block !important;
}

.ButtonMenu #toggle {
  display: none;
}

.ButtonMenu label {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 8;
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.MainMenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 320px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
  z-index: 8;
  opacity: 0;
  right: -320px;
}

#toggle:checked~.MainMenu {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

#NavDark {
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#toggle:checked~#NavDark {
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ButtonMenu">

  <input id='toggle' type='checkbox' />
  <label for='toggle'>
<img src="/img/image 8.png" alt="hamburger icon">
</label>

  <div id="NavDark">


  </div>
  <div class='MainMenu'>

    {{ range .Site.Menus.main }}

    <a href="{{ .URL }}" class="navbar-item" title="{{ .Name }}">             {{ .Name }}</a> {{ end }}

  </div>
</div>
```

I need help on how to make the label only needing one click each time to show the menu.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please create a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a CSS-jQuery compatibility issiue. In your CSS, visibility of `.MainMenu` and `#NavDark` is controlled by wether the checkbox is checked:

```
#toggle:checked~.MainMenu {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
#toggle:checked~#NavDark {
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

In your JS, however, visibility of the two elements is controlled (internally) via the `style=""` display value. Now the following happens:

- Initially, the checkbox is unchecked, and the inline style attribute is missing, which means the two elements have their default value of `display:block`, but are moved offscreen by the CSS.
- Now we click the label. The checkbox gets checked, and the CSS relocates them onscreen. The JS click handler of `#toggle` runs, but because the style attribute already (implicitly) is `block`, nothing happens.
- Now we click `#NavDark` to close the menu. The JS handler of `#NavDark` runs, and sets the inline style value to `display:hidden`, so they hide. The ckeckbox hasn't been altered by either the click nor JS code, so **it remains checked**.
- Now we click the label again. The checkbox gets toggled, so it is now unchecked, and as a result CSS moves the (would-be) position of `.MainMenu` and `#NavDark` **to be ofscreen**. the JS handler runs, and removes `display:none`, but the two elements are offscreen and so don't display.
- during the second click, the JS does nothing, as the style attribute says they're already visible, but the checkbox gets checked, so it moves the two elements back onscreen.

Additionally, your `z-index` values appear to be off, which means that `.MainMenu` displays *behind* `#NavDark` and is unclickable.

As for a fix, [Edited 2024-01-02, see comments] you do not need JS at all (see Roko C. Buljan's answer on how that could work) or you could ditch all JS except for The #NavDark handler, which only realy needs to uncheck the checkbox; CSS will hide the menu.

```
$("#NavDark").click(function() {
  $("#toggle").prop("checked", false);
});
```

```js
$("#NavDark").click(function() {
  /*
    uncheck the checkbox, thereby hiding the nav menu.
  */
  $("#toggle").prop("checked", false);
});
```

```css
.ButtonMenu label:checked~.MainMenu {
  display: block !important;
}

.ButtonMenu #toggle {
  display: none;
}

.ButtonMenu label {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 8;
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.MainMenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 320px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
  z-index: 120;
  /* new z-index to reflect  #NavDark */
  opacity: 0;
  right: -320px;
}

#toggle:checked~.MainMenu {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

#NavDark {
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#toggle:checked~#NavDark {
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ButtonMenu">
  <input id='toggle' type='checkbox' />
  <label for='toggle'>
<img src="/img/image 8.png" alt="hamburger">
</label>
  <div id="NavDark"></div>
  <div class='MainMenu'>
    {{ range .Site.Menus.main }}

    <a href="{{ .URL }}" class="navbar-item" title="{{ .Name }}">             {{ .Name }}</a> {{ end }}

  </div>
</div>
```

As a side note, I agree with Roko C. Buljan that your code has indenting issiues (I ran Tidy on the snippets, to show you how it can look) and that your ID's and class names could be brought up to standard. In the HTMLCSS world, you nowadays pretty much always see lowercase-dashed-names, though sometimes camelCaseNames are still used.

Comment: Edited in a fix for incorrect `z-index´ values

Comment: Thanks for your answer; The first methode works but without style , not translated as i want when i click in second time on label of menu ! any ideas to see style (   transform: translateX(-100%); )

Comment: @Nedjma Média Thanks, I have reworked my answer so that the CSS transition works.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't necessarily need JS at all.
- Rename better your attributes ID values.
- Better nest your markup. Keep the input in root on DOM top.
- Use `:checked` to translare a single element `#menu-wrapper`
- Use CSS `pointer-events` to remove preserve or pass-through clicks and other pointer events

```css
#btn-hamburger {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  z-index: 8;
  display: inline-block !important;
}

[for="menu-toggle"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100dvh; /* use dvh units */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  transition: translate 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
  translate: 100% 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none; /* let clicks pass-through */
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 320px;
  height: 100dvh;   /* use dvh units */
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: auto; /* preserve clicks */
}

#menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

#menu-toggle:checked ~ #menu-wrapper {
  translate: 0% 0%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input id="menu-toggle" type="checkbox" />
<label id="btn-hamburger" for="menu-toggle">hamburger icon</label>

<div id="menu-wrapper">
  <div id="menu">
    <label for="menu-toggle" title="Close menu">CLOSE &times;</label>
    <h3>Menu...</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the issue might be related to the order of operations in your JavaScript. The click event for #toggle is showing both .MainMenu and #NavDark, but the click event for #NavDark is only hiding them.

To solve this issue, you can modify your JavaScript to toggle the visibility of both elements when #toggle is clicked.

updated js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    $(".MainMenu, #NavDark").toggle();
  });

  $("#NavDark").click(function() {
    $(".MainMenu, #NavDark").hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: with this i can't close menu , not working if you have other suggestions please !